# How to disable pdf,word export option in rdlc report in mvc razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I am trying to give only Excel export option in report viewer tools in mvc5 razor view .I tried following code but still toolbar shows pdf,word option.

```
LocalReport server1 = reportViewer.LocalReport;
FieldInfo mField;
foreach (RenderingExtension e in server1.ListRenderingExtensions())
{
    if (e.Name.Trim() == "PDF")
    {
        mField = e.GetType().GetField("m_isVisible", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        mField.SetValue(e, false);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-RDLC-Local-SSRS-Report-Viewer-Hide-Disable-specific-export-option-Word-Excel-PDF-from-Export-button.aspx

Working demo (Check radio buttons to make options hidden): https://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/912/